# Angular2 Meteor Bind Data from calling this.call

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

**Methods**

```
Meteor.methods({
    'test' : function(test: string) {
        return test;
    }
})
```

**Component**

My Class extends `MeteorComponent`

```
show: string;
constructor() {
     this.call('test', 'txt', (err, res) => {
          this.show = res
     });
}
```

**view**

```
<span>{{show}}</span>
```

it shows nothing, as I expect it will show 'txt'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `autorun`, `call` has no parameter to tell it to run inside the `NgZone`, so Angular's change-detection won't kick in.

You'll need to write it this way:

```
constructor(zone: NgZone) {
  this.call('test', 'txt', (err, res) => {
    zone.run(() => {
      this.show = res;
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add an explanation for @Martin C.'s answer.

In Angular2-Meteor 0.5.6 (not published to NPM yet), you should be able to use `autoBind`.

```
  this.call('test', 'txt', (err, res) => {
    this.show = res;
  }, true);  // set `autoBind` to `true` here
```

https://github.com/Urigo/angular2-meteor/issues/279

Comment: I think need to use ([err, res]), as the result returned is array after giving the true value