# Angular 2 binding seems to be removed after an async operation

Tags: angular

I have a `login()` function and in my template, there's a `{{message}}` variable that's bound to the component.

Here's the login function:

```js
login() {
     this.busy = true;
     this.message = 'Trying to log in ...'; // correctly updates the template here
     this.authService.login().subscribe(
         () => {
             this.busy = false;
             if(!this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                 return;
             }
             this.router.navigate(['/']);
         },
         error => { 
            console.log(this.message);
            console.error(error);
            this.busy = false;
            this.setErrorMessage();
            console.log(this.message);
        }  
     );  
 }
```

The problem is that inside the "error" callback, when I call `this.setErrorMessage()`, the template doesn't get update.
I did a `console.log(this)` after `this.setErrorMessage()` and the component variables are indeed set correctly, but it's not reflected in the HTML.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**
Updated the `error` function. Also tried with .catch() as @Günter Zöchbauer suggested. No luck tho.

Here's the `setErrorMessage()` function:

```js
setErrorMessage() {
     this.message = 'There was an error while trying to log you in. Please try again in a few moments!'
 }
```

The relevant template part:

```html
<p id="GB-login-frame-text">
  {{message}}
</p>
```

The `authService.login()` function returns an `Observable` like so:

```js
login():Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + "/login", {headers: this.headers()})
        .map(this.parseResponse)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

The `parseResponse` and `handleError` functions:

```js
private parseResponse(response:Response):any {
    let result = response.json();
    return result.data || {};
}    

private handleError(error:any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
        error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    if(error.status == 401) {
        localStorage.removeItem('user');
        window.location.href = '/login';
        return;
    }    
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

And the console output when the `error` function is called:

```
Trying to log in ...
login.component.ts:39 Object {error: "A generic error occurred"}(anonymous function) @ login.component.ts:39SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.error @ Subscriber.ts:204Subscriber._error @ Subscriber.ts:137Subscriber.error @ Subscriber.ts:107(anonymous function) @ auth.service.ts:50SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:240SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:192Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:133Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:93onLoad @ http.umd.js:1104ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:356Zone.runTask @ zone.js:256ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:423
login.component.ts:42 There was an error while trying to log you in. Please try again in a few moments!
```

The `message` is being updated correctly in the component `js` part it seems, but it does not reflect in `html`.

Comment: Could you show us the template and the `setErrorMessage` method?

Comment: Done, but that code is very trivial.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: If it is really change detection failing, the error callback might not run in the `NgZone` of Angular2 (if this is the case, you should open an issue in the issue tracker). Try wrapping it a `error => zone.run(() => { ... })`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849791/angular2-meteor-bind-data-from-calling-this-call/37857413#3785741 for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comments on the question and in the other answers the issue seems to be that change detection for error does not kick in, which is mostly the case if it is not run in the `NgZone` of Angular2. I would consider this a bug, but it's possible.

You can use wrap it as follows then:

```js
constructor(private zone:NgZone) {
    // ...
}

login() {
   this.busy = true;
   this.message = 'Trying to log in ...'; // correctly updates the template here
   this.authService.login().subscribe(
       () => {
           this.busy = false;
           if(!this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
               return;
           }
           this.router.navigate(['/']);
       },
       error => this.zone.run(() => { 
          console.log(this.message);
          console.error(error);
          this.busy = false;
          this.setErrorMessage();
          console.log(this.message);
      })
   );  
 }
```

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer. Also +1 @Günter since his input helped on figuring this out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `catch()` to ensure that code is executed properly after an error, otherwise when an exception happens, change detection won't run on the component:

```
login() {
     this.busy = true;
     this.message = 'Trying to log in ...'; // correctly updates the template here
     this.authService.login()
     .catch( // needs import
         error => {
             console.error(error);
             this.busy = false;
             this.setErrorMessage();
             return Observable.of([]); // needs import
         }   
     })
     .subscribe(
         () => {
             this.busy = false;
             if(!this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                 return;
             }
             this.router.navigate(['/']);
         }
     );  
 }
```

Comment: The Prototype for an `Observable` is `Rx.Observable.prototype.subscribe([observer] | [onNext], [onError], [onCompleted])`. So it will catch errors.

Comment: @MartinC. I would expect this behavior but if change detection fails after an error, it doesn't look like the error is cought. I didn't fully investigate the situation mentioned in the question, but I have seen that change detection fails to run after an exception is thrown in a component.

Comment: Then maybe it is not running inside the `NgZone` and it needs to be wrapped in a `zone.run(() => {...})`. Similar issue would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37849791/angular2-meteor-bind-data-from-calling-this-call/37857413#3785741 then.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer you are correct about change detection failing. I've used the ChangeDetectorRef and manually triggered `detectChanges()` and the template updates correctly. This is a bit of a hack, but it'll work for now since I really can't spend more time on this to find the root cause.